# How to access kubernetes CRD using client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-go-client, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have few CRDs, but I am not exactly sure how to query kube-apiserver  to get list of CRs. Can anyone please provide any sample code?

Comment: Any news? I read that kubebuilder can be used for this. But I cannot understand, If I need just to get status of the CR, why I need to generate whole new api resource. 
I just want to expose some metrics about CRDs for prometheus(

Comment: where is the code running? in the cluster or out of the cluster? [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples) are examples from the client-go repo.

Answer (score 2):

my sample code for an out of cluster config

```
    var kubeconfig *string
    kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "./config", "(optional) relative path to the kubeconfig file")
    flag.Parse()

    // kubernetes config loaded from ./config or whatever the flag was set to
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // instantiate our client with config
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // get a list of our CRs
    pl := PingerList{}
    d, err := clientset.RESTClient().Get().AbsPath("/apis/pinger.hel.lo/v1/pingers").DoRaw(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &pl); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

PingerList{} is an object generated from Kubebuilder that I unmarshal to later in the code. However, you could just straight up `println(string(d))` to get that json.

The components in the AbsPath() are `"/apis/group/verison/plural version of resource name"`

if you're using minikube, you can get the config file with `kubectl config view`

Kubernetes-related imports are the following

```
"k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
"k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
```

Comment: Can I get a particular element of CR from AbsPath function? 
I mean `kubectl get pingers <particular pinger> related to your code.`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this page to get information on how to access the crd using this [repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiextensions-apiserver/blob/master/pkg/client/clientset/clientset/typed/apiextensions/v1beta1/customresourcedefinition.go)

and for more information refer this document
[document](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/kubernetes-deep-dive-code-generation-customresources)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29981440)

Comment: Ok will keep that in mind and will edit the answer too

Answer (score -4):

Either you need to use the Unstructured client, or generate a client stub. The dynamic client in the controller-runtime library is a lot nicer for this and I recommend it.